# Mongo C# driver find multiple and delete

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using collection.FindOneAndDeleteAsync, but this uses a ton of cpu when used to get many documents. What's the best way to go about finding multiple documents(anywhere from 100 to 50k) and delete, using the c# mongo driver?

Thanks

Comment: As long as you don't also need the deleted documents returned, `DeleteMany` will give you the best performance. Is that an option for you?

Comment: The issue is, that i do.
That's why i'm using FindOneAndDelete.

Comment: Would it be better to FindMany and then remove those after?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thanks. Feel free to add as answer and i'll pick it. Really just needed to know the most efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to `Find` the docs you want to delete, and then delete them using `DeleteMany` with a filter of `_id: {$in: ids}`, where `ids` is an enumerable of the `_id` values of those documents.

C# example:

```
public class Entity
{
    public ObjectId id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

// Find the documents to delete
var test = db.GetCollection<Entity>("test");
var filter = new BsonDocument();
var docs = test.Find(filter).ToList();

// Get the _id values of the found documents
var ids = docs.Select(d => d.id);

// Create an $in filter for those ids
var idsFilter = Builders<Entity>.Filter.In(d => d.id, ids);

// Delete the documents using the $in filter
var result = test.DeleteMany(idsFilter);
```

Comment: I am getting this error: MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command delete failed: query in command must target a single shard key.'